# Make CSS3 triangle with linear gradient

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-shapes

I need to create button with triangle on one side (like this **http://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/**) with linear vertical gradient and border, and I want to use pure CSS3.
It's ok if I need 45deg "triangle", I just write smth like this

```
.button:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff, #000);
    content: '';
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    display: block;
}
```

and hide half of that pseudo-element under .button (so only another half of it is visible, like a triangle).

But if I need another angle (e.g. more steep) - I can't make it with standart XY rotate and scale. I can use e.g. 2 divs, one for top half of triangle and one for bottom, but there might be a problem with border and gradient.

Maybe it's possible to do that with multiple gradients with color stops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help you i have made gradient triangle with only one div with pure css.

http://jsfiddle.net/NDJ3S/15/

**UPDATED**

Check it now its working :- http://jsfiddle.net/NDJ3S/17/

Answer (score 10):

So I know that you want to do this with CSS, but I always do this in SVG:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<defs>
<linearGradient id="fill" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
<stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(224,224,224);stop-opacity:1"/>
<stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(153,153,153);stop-opacity:1"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>

<path d="M 0 0 L 64 0 L 32 64 z" stroke="colourname" fill="url(#fill)"/>

</svg>
```

You can embed it as so:

```
<img src="triangle.svg" alt="Triangle" class="triangle" />
```

You could also make the toggle image in the same way, and toggle it using JavaScript or jQuery:

```
$(".triangle").click(function()
{
    if($(this).attr("src") == "triangle.svg")
        $(this).attr("src", "triangledown.svg");

    else $(this).attr("src", "triangle.svg");
});
```

Comment: I know about SVG, but I'm still wondering if there is another way (CSS)

Comment: My only concern with using CSS is that the border-image property is not compatible with IE9.

Answer (score 10):

Just use `clip-path` with `background-image`

```css
.triangle {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.4), rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5));
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: As CSS should be as intuitive as possible, I find this the best answer. The rule should be: 'First, see if there is a property that is specially designed for it. ' And `clip-path` is, in this case.

Comment: @FrankConijn-SupportUkraine This is the best answer and has been the best answer for years now. However, when the question was asked 12 years ago, back in May 2012, `clip-path` was not yet supported in any browser yet. Chrome support only came 6 months later, Safari support a year and a half later. For about half a decade after this question was asked, Firefox didn't support basic shapes for `clip-path`. Edge support only came a while after the switch from Trident to Chromium, about half a decade ago. So while `clip-path` is THE solution today, it wasn't always available.

Answer (score 8):

#### **Edit 2024 as I was horrified to learn Gemini AI references my decade old answer as the top method for creating a gradient triangle: please don't do this nowadays anymore! Use [Owen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69124269/1397351) as `clip-path` is the way to go these days - it has been supported cross-browser for years and it's by far the best way to get such a result (it's simpler, restricts clicks to the triangular area, works for image backgrounds behind the triangle).**

---

**Original answer, preserved for web history reasons - please don't do this anymore**

Yes, it can be done using only CSS gradients. You just have to put three gradients on top of the other (keep in mind that *the first one you list is the one on top*). The one at the bottom (last one listed) is your vertical gradient. On top of it, you have two gradients which also make use of color stops.

Something like this:

```css
div {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 64%, #fff 66%), 
                linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 64%, #fff 66%), 
                linear-gradient(tomato, black);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the css transform scaleY?
With another element around the arrow (or perhaps with a pseudo element) it enables you to rescale the result.

```
transform: scaleY(0.5)
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xaddict/hJyrU/ (webkit-only example)

EDIT: added `translateZ(0)` to force GPU rendering in webkit (anti-aliased borders, mhmmmm!)