# Is it possible to make CSS triangles / arrows that aren't your typical right angled triangles with a gradient applied?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I know that to create a basic arrow in CSS I can do this:

```
<div class="arrow-button">
    <span class="arrow-tip-container">
         <span class="arrow-tip"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then all I'll have to do is rotate and position the container then fill the arrow-tip and **BAM!** there;s a sweet arrow: http://jsfiddle.net/uF69S/

However, I want an arrow where the tip is effectively a 120° angle, so is it possible to achieve this effect using CSS transforms or two different containers? Maybe a skew and a rotate?

I would like to create this arrow:

```
------------\
|            \
|            /
------------/
```

Notice that the arrowhead is **not** 90°.

**NOTE:**
I am aware that border triangle could be used to make any angle of triangle, however they do **not** support gradients in Firefox, Opera or IE, whereas Firefox, Opera and IE can support transforms (in one way or another).

Comment: You can make actual triangles using border hacks; that might help.

Comment: Have been looking for the solution as well. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580226/make-css3-triangle-with-linear-gradient). You may want to consider doing this with SVG.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use skew for making triangle of 120 degree like this:

```
.arrow-tip {
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 0 0 -20px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) skew(20deg,20deg);
 }
```

Also : http://jsfiddle.net/95Xq8/

Comment: perfect, i tried this before, just couldn't get the angles right; just as a note to anyone looking, this solution **is** compatible ie7 and up providing you use this beautiful transforms to ie filters converter: http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

Answer (score 3):

This might be a start:

HTML:

```
<div>▲</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div {
  font-size: 46px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(.3);
}​
```

View it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wyty/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you opposed to using HTML5 Canvas? It is supported for IE9+ (per [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas)).

This will get you started:
http://www.dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/canvas/CanvasArrow.html

Comment: im not opposed, but I'm hoping for an ie7 + solution, and I'm sure something must be possible with all the power of css

Comment: If you are stuck supporting IE7, then NO, I highly doubt you'll be able to do this in CSS. Use an image and save yourself a migraine.