# Creating triangles

Tags: css

I'm creating a wordpress theme and both sides of the content should have diagonally border. I can solve this with pictures but this is the ugly way and the content has not the same length on every page.

In this case i think two triangles on the right and left side is the correct solution. I tried it with [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-diagonal-lines-with-css/), but the problem is that I have to use fixed width for the borders and the triangle should have the height of the content, dynamically adjusted.

How can I solve this, that I come up with two triangles (marked red in the sketch).

[image]

Comment: +1 for giving an image explaining your problem

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this (albeit somewhat imprecisely) with the CSS skew transform:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/cUWm2/2/

```
<div class="shape">
    A variable amount of content.
</div>
```

```css
.shape {
    position: relative;
}
.shape:before {
    content:"";
    -moz-transform: skewX(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(10deg);
    transform: skewX(10deg);
    width: 140%;
    left: -20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

This achieves the requested shape with minimal markup and decent (IE9+ and all other modern) browser support. However, when scaling height up or down, eventually the triangles cease to be triangles and a fourth edge becomes visible. You have several options:

1. Find dimensions that work for a practical amount of content and code to that.
2. Dynamically alter the skew amount using JavaScript.
3. Blend the background of the edge shapes with the main shape.
4. Ignore it (depending on the layout, it doesn't necessarily look bad).

All that said (after playing with various CSS options) I'd probably consider an image-centric solution first. You can use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to create containers which resize vertically along with your main content while staying the same width. You can then use a background image to cover the desired area, or put a 100% x 100% image into the container.

Comment: +1 for an interesting solution, although I can't help feeling that using the "traditional" method of creating triangles in CSS would be more suitable here as it's better supported and somewhat cleaner

Comment: Yeah, I've been playing with it for the last half hour...it's cool but not terribly practical (especially with dynamic heights). I may post a better solution if I can stay awake that long :)

Comment: I've just attempted to make dynamically sized triangles using the border method and failed miserably. All these solutions depend on fixed values and, to make things worse, don't support percentages

Comment: I tried the same thing (and several other routes). I didn't find anything that could precisely cover the dynamic height. `background-size: cover` would probably be the easiest route.

Answer (score 1):

I also agree with using SVGs. I find them easier to manipulate since they're scalable and cross compatible between browsers as they're images. Here's an answer I posted to a similar question, which should get you started: [Make CSS3 triangle with linear gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580226/make-css3-triangle-with-linear-gradient/10580899#10580899)

From there, it will be easy to set the image heights to match the content's. Here's a jQuery example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".triangle").height($(".content").height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by the use of SVGs (Scaleable Vector Graphics). You create the two triangle-SVGs and then make a 3 column layout where all columns are equally heigh (for example by using display: table-cell). You chose the left triangle as background-image for the left column and the right triangle as bg-image for the right one. The middle one is for your content.

Dont forget to use preserveAspectRatio(https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) in your SVG.