# How to make half-square background in css

Tags: css, css-shapes

[image: square cut in half diagonaly]

Is it possible to make in pure css background for half square like on the image.
I know that it can be done with an image as background, but I need to use 5 different colours, and maybe in future the colours can be changed.

Comment: might find this [css triangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) useful

Comment: There are [several](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) [different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580226/make-css3-triangle-with-linear-gradient) ways to go about doing this, such as using multiple elements or a gradient. I'd recommend googling abit to find the solution that meets your needs the best.

Comment: The problem with this design approach is that the half-square motif as a CSS element cannot be used in the CSS `background` property.  So you will need to use CSS positioning to put it in place.  This seems to be a lot of trouble to avoid creating 5 images and maybe a few more in the future.  In this case, you are creating extra mark-up for a visual effect that may best be implemented using standard CSS properties.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your divs have fixed sizes, you can use borders to make two triangles as described in  [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work):

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  border-top:100px solid red;
  border-right:100px solid grey;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

To make other sizes, colors, you need to tweak the border properties :

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  border-right: 100px solid red;
  border-top: 100px solid grey;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: 100px solid red;
  border-top: 100px solid grey;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: 50px solid red;
  border-top: 100px solid grey;
}
div:nth-child(4) {
  border-right: 100px solid red;
  border-bottom: 50px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also try [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(248, 80, 50, 1);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,grey 50%,red 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use transform if you don't need to worry about old browser support.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #E30606;
}
.overlay {
  width: 171px;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #D0CBCB;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hT9vP/13/