# Availability Calendar Cell Colour

Tags: css, calendar

I'm using the script below to crate an availability calendar for my website. The guests check-out on a Saturday morning and check-in on Saturday afternoon.

[Availability Calendar](https://www.phpjabbers.com/free-availability-calendar-script/)

Therefore trying to adapt the code to resemble:

[image]

Just cant get the code to look right if two weeks booked together and also the first Unavaiolable cell is always highlighted as the last nth etc.

Comment: You can create two triangles using CSS inside that box. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819606

Comment: @ManojKumar thank you, thats a better way of setting the background than using linear gradients. The main issue is how to implement the css in the datepicker code.

Comment: Managed to add the CSS code and change the datepicker code. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Answer your own question and mark it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the relevant CSS as a previous question noted by @Manoj Kumar.

Due to the HTML being created via JS, checks had to be undertaken in JavaScript on NextStatus and PrevStatus to determine the CSS to use and whether Available or not.