# CSS triangle with gradient

Tags: css, svg, gradient, css-shapes

I'm trying to achieve a **triangle filled with a gradient**.
The triangle should sit in the top left hand corner of the page and stretch 50% of the horizontal viewport and 120% of the vertical viewport.

I need the **triangle to have a gradient running through it**.
I've managed to do the first three things but I can't get the gradient to work.
I've tried positioning pseudo elements in different ways with overflow and also `transform: rotate();` to achieve it but I just can't get it to work.

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3w08n8h6/) of what I have so far :

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0 120vh 50vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Why is this target with javascript and jquery?

Comment: I removed the javascript and jquery tags.

Comment: Just incase there's a JS or JQuery way of achieving this, which I'm open too as it seems quite hack-y doing it with pure CSS.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Comment: What are your requirements regarding browser compatibility? There should be an easy solution using a background gradient and clip-path, but browser support is stilla a bit limited as of yet: https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: Yeah clip path was my first port of call using - https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ - but the I need to support IE9+ so I had to find an alternative.

Comment: try this - [example](https://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/ILJAl)

Comment: [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580226/make-css3-triangle-with-linear-gradient)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To keep the proportions you need, you can use an [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) with the `preserveAspectRatio="none"` property ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)). This way, the width and height are fixed to the viewport unit you used.
You can use the [polygon element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon) to make the triangle and the [linearGradient element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient) to **fill the triangle with a gradient** :

```css
svg {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="darkorange" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <polygon fill="url(#gradient)" points="0 0 10 0 0 10" />
</svg>
```

Comment: SVG! I didn't even think of that. This will work perfectly as it's so much cleaner than the other CSS solutions out there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice solution bro.

Answer (score 3):

Use `clip-path`:

```css
.triangle {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 80vmin;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

You can simply adjust the values as you need.

Comment: The issue with this is that you can't keep the proportions of the triangle as the OP needs.

Comment: @web-tiki we can but this will invole to make some calculation in order to achieve it. But i agree that it can be complex